# On construction of Hilbert and Quot schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, schemes, hilbert-schemes

I have some questions regarding the *strategy* of the proof of the existence of Hilbert and Quot schemes (I will focus on the latter since it's more general), as in the book *Fundamental Algebraic Geometry–Grothendieck's FGA Explained*. (I have just a sketch of the related part and not go into the details yet.)

(1) I find the basic setting is restricted to the category ${\rm Sch}^{\rm locnoe}_S$ of locally noetherian schemes over a fixed locally noetherian schemes $S$. I think it first proves representability of the functor $\mathfrak{Q}uot_{E/X/S}$ in this category ${\rm Sch}^{\rm locnoe}_S$, then through Yoneda lemma, we can find a locally noetherian scheme ${\rm Quot}_{E/X/S}$ representing the functor $\mathfrak{Q}uot_{E/X/S}$, then we in particular regard this scheme ${\rm Quot}_{E/X/S}$ as in ${\rm Sch}_S$, the category of *all* $S$-schemes. Am I correct? (In my opinion, people only want it to be an $S$-scheme a priori; being locally noetherian is an extra property.)

(2) This is more crucial to me. The following picture is from p.110 of the above-mentioned book.

[image]

I think, in general, Yoneda embedding doesn't commute with coproducts, i.e., we don't have $h_{\coprod Y_i}\cong\coprod h_{Y_i}$. How can one get a coproduct decomposition of the representative from a coproduct decomposition of the corresponding functor (in our situation, $\mathfrak{Q}uot_{E/X/S}$)?

Thanks in advance for those who answer my doubts!

Comment: The first coproduct decomposition does not actually take place in the category of presheaves. It takes place in the subcategory of product-preserving presheaves. The Yoneda embedding into that subcategory preserves coproducts.

Comment: You can use limit theorems as in EGA III to reduce representability to the Noetherian case, cf. the comments to the following MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259423/standard-limit-arguments-involved-in-showing-that-roughly-every-dm-stack-is-lo

Comment: @ Marc Hoyois Thanks Marc! By "product-preserving presheaves", do you mean those presheaves taking (arbitrary) coproducts to products? (Namely, you are using that products in the opposite category are coproducts in the original one?)

Comment: @Marc Hoyois Moreover, I think in the category of product-preserving presheaves, the value of the coproduct of (say two) product-preserving presheaves on an object is not simply the coproduct (i.e. disjoint union) of the values of these presheaves.

Comment: Indeed, and correspondingly the value of the functor Quot on a non-connected scheme is not simply the coproduct of the values of the functors Quot^Phi, one has to make the latter product-preserving.

Comment: By the way it is well-known that the noetherian assumptions in Grothendieck's presentation of the Quot scheme are not essential, but I do not know a reference. It might be in the Stacks project.

Comment: @Marc Hoyois Thanks! To "make the latter (presheaf) product-preserving", can I understand as the sheafification of the presheaf $Q$ in question w.r.t. the topology whose covers (of an object X) are given by coproduct decompositions $\coprod_i U_i\cong X$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This sheafification does not change the values on connected schemes, so it's also clear what it does on disjoint unions of connected schemes (e.g. locally noetherian schemes).

Comment: Great, thanks Marc! I can be sure (2) is not a problem for me now: we first sheafify the coproduct decomposition of functor in that book to a  coproduct decomposition in the category of sheaves for the topology whose covers are given by coproduct decompositions (and use that representable functors are still sheaves).

Comment: ...to confirm that the Yoneda embedding followed by sheafification is fully faithful.

Comment: To record, see also here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44516/non-representable-functor-representable-on-locally-noetherian-schemes?rq=1#comment106319_44516 for (1) on locally noetherian assumption.